# Connecting multiple laptops using chrome to chromecast

Tags: google-cast

I have set up the project much like the tictactoe sample game. However, when using the chrome sender, I can only connect one at a time. If I connect the second laptop using the chrome sender, then it kills the first session and restarts a session.

Is it possible to connect multiple chrome tabs/browsers to the same chromecast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does TicTacToe work for you? If it does, you need to follow the same pattern for handling incoming senders. If it doesn't, file a bug with that project on our GitHub repo with the details.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I replicated the TicTacToe game with a different appID, and namespace. However, I run into the same issue.

Comment: Then please follow up on the GitHub with an issue for that project.

Comment: "SOLVED" the second player needs to perform a second click to cast to the chromecast on the chromecast popup.